# save part of camera capture in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I am trying to save only the face detected by the camara (crop the face from the image).
I have implemented the 2 PictureCallback methods for jpg and raw, but I don't understand how it works, because I get only a byte[] array. I want to be able to analyze the byte[] array and only save the face area.

PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback() {

```
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                //How to save only part of the data? I don't know the width/height or the format!
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

byte array are the bytes representing either the jpg or raw data as taken by your camera

Any parameters you will be able to get from the Camera object itself such as `Camera.getParameters().getPictureSize()` or `getPictureFormat()`